# Why does java compiler not check the object type in a list argument until fetched?

Tags: java, list, generics, casting

Java compiler does not seem to care if the type in the list matches until the object needs to be fetched:

```
private static void print(List<Integer> list) { //private static <T> void print(List<T> list) { will also do
    for (Object object: list)
        System.out.print(object);
    int int0 = list.get(0); //ok
    //int int1 = list.get(1); //ClassCastException if run
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(1);
    list.add("2");
    print(list);
}
```

Comment: [Type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Also, don't use [raw types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).

Comment: `list` is of *raw type* - allowed for compatibility of older code - kind of turns of type checking (well, there is no type to check).

Comment: All those warnings that you are ignoring count as "caring".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java compiler didn't checked the types of elements that you added to the list, since you declared raw type:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
```

Then during execution you tried to assign `String` to `int`, that caused `ClassCastException` at runtime.

You didn't got exception on this line `int int0 = list.get(0);`, because auto-boxing (in this case un-boxing).

Precisely this sort of problems led to introducing [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html) to Java language. So, in order the compiler to check types that are put to the list, you need to change declaration to:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

This will tell compiler to check the types of values added to list and enforce them to be `Integer`s. So, basically run-time error will be eliminated and replaced by compile-time error.

Comment: on the other side the list could be declared as `List<Object> list = ...` to accept any kind of instances, but `print(list)` would raise a compile error

Comment: You are right. This is because `List<Object>` and `List<Integer>` are different types, and compiler catches it. It really depends on what the goals of the `List` is. If it should contain `Object`s, then it shouldn't be passed to the method, that takes `List<Integer>`, and compiler rightly catches it.

Answer (score 0):

Typed definition like `List<Integer>` has exactly the purpose to **prevent** such errors. But you used `List list` without any type and thus you **refused** to get information about errors during compilation, before you run your program.

Declare the list with a specific type

```
List<Integher> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

... and Java compiler will show you your errors. You will see that following line is marked as an error:

```
list.add("2");
```